Is Number Operator a Generalized Momentum?
In superconducting circuit, the number operator, $\hat{n}$, and phase operator, $\hat{\varphi}$ are conjugate pairs. Is $\hat{n}$ the canonical momentum, conjugate momentum, and also generalized momentum? Are they the same?

Classically, two canonical coordinates $q,p$ must satisfy the Poisson brackets, and for quantum systems the canonical commutation relation $[\hat{q},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$.In this case referring to $\hat{p}$ as the momentum conjugate to $\hat{q}$ ~or~ as the canonical momentum are both appropriate. Generalized momentum usually refers to momenta derived from Lagrangians, but the Hamilton-Jacobi equations can be used to find the canonical coordinates. So to answer your four questions: yes, yes, not really but it's kinda splitting hairs, sometimes.
